# Identifying era of Family Bible posted on Facebook?

Tags: bible

I was contacted about a family bible for an ancestor of my wife and which has been [posted on FaceBook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1052873914775100/permalink/1732997350096083) with some photos, including these two:

[image: Deaths]
[image: Family Portraits]

From the posted pictures, is there enough information to gauge how old the printing is?  (E.g., is this early 20<sup>th</sup> century or late 19<sup>th</sup> century bible?)  Do the photographed "Deaths" and "Family Photos" headers shown above provide a recognizable signature to deduce the likely edition or range of editions or other identifying information about this family bible?

Comment: In order to answer your two questions (there should really be only one), I think it would be helpful for you to crop the relevant part of an image and post it here.  Potential answerers may not be willing to follow links to Facebook in order to understand the question.  Providing links for more background is fine.

Comment: I don't think this can realistically be answered so if I had a normal vote would have voted to leave closed. There are thousands of editions of the bible, and I would be very surprised if anyone can identify the exact edition. And if they do, to what purpose? The information and photos in a family bible won't all have come from the same year, they might not even be from the same century. The photos could pre-date the bible itself. I think you would be better posting the particular photos of interest individually (but probably not all at once) for dating or identification of a specific aspect.

Comment: @PolyGeo Images added.

Comment: @HarryVervet Tried to make question more answerable.

Comment: Who has the Bible? Why can't the owner look at the publication date and tell you?

Comment: @JanMurphy It is in a store in Arkansas.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the provenance the shop owner claims is valid? that's an Antiques Roadshow problem, not a Genealogy Roadshow problem. I have some other comments & will leave them in chat.